# TypeError uploading image file to Amazon S3 in Django using BOTO Library

Tags: python, django, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto

I am a total beginner to programming and Django so I'd appreciate help that beginner can get his head round!

I was following a tutorial to show how to upload images to an Amazon S3 account with the Boto library but I think it is for an older version of Django (I'm on 1.1.2 and Python 2.65) and something has changed. I get an error: 
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:    'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is unsubscriptable

My code is:

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime

class PhotoUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField()
    def save(self):
        self.uploaded = datetime.now()
        models.Model.save(self)
```

**views.py:**

```
import mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

def awsdemo(request):   
def store_in_s3(filename, content):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    b = conn.create_bucket('almacmillan-hark')
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = filename
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
    k.set_contents_from_strong(content)
    k.set_acl("public-read")

photos = PhotoUrl.objects.all().order_by("-uploaded")
if not request.method == "POST":
    f = UploadForm()
    return render_to_response('awsdemo.html', {'form':f, 'photos':photos})

f = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if not f.is_valid():
    return render_to_response('awsdemo.html', {'form':f, 'photos':photos})

file = request.FILES['file']
filename = file.name
content = file['content']
store_in_s3(filename, content)
p = PhotoUrl(url="http://almacmillan-hark.s3.amazonaws.com/" + filename)
p.save()
photos = PhotoUrl.objects.all().order_by("-uploaded")   
return render_to_response('awsdemo.html', {'form':f, 'photos':photos})
```

**urls.py:**

```
(r'^awsdemo/$', 'harkproject.s3app.views.awsdemo'),
```

**awsdemo.html:**

```
<div class="form">
    <strong>{{form.file.label}}</strong>
    <form method="POST" action ="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{form.file}}<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form> 
</div>
```

I'd really appreciate help. I hope I have provided enough code.

Kind regards
AL

Comment: One thing I see right off the bat:  `k.set_contents_from_strong(content)` should really be `set_contents_from_string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
content = file['content']
```

From the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES):

> Each value in FILES is an UploadedFile object containing the following attributes:
>
> - read(num_bytes=None) -- Read a number of bytes from the file.
> - name -- The name of the uploaded file.
> - size -- The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
> - chunks(chunk_size=None) -- A generator that yields sequential chunks of data.

Try this instead:

```
content = file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Django Storages](http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/wiki/Home)? That way you only have to specify a storage backend (s3boto in this case) either as the default storage backend, or supply it as an argument to a FileField or ImageField class.